# ios there is a way to combined switch cases?

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I was wondering if there is a way to combined switch cases for example:

```
   switch (value)
   {
   case 0,1,2:
      nslog (@"0,1,2 cases");
      break
      case 3:
      nslog (@"3 cases");
        break;
      default:
        NSLog (@"anything else");
        break;
   }
```

I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You mean, something like this?

```
switch (value)
{
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
  NSLog (@"0,1,2 cases");
  break;
case 3:
  NSLog (@"3 cases");
  break;
default:
  NSLog (@"anything else");
  break;
}
```

You know, the switch case structure will execute each line inside the braces starting from the corresponding case line, until it reach the last one or a break. So, if you don't include a break after a case, it will go on executing the next case also.

Comment: How about the ugly way of combining: switch(value / 3) { case 0: nslog (@"0,1,2 cases"); break; case 1: nslog (@"3 cases"); break; default:   NSLog (@"anything else"); break; }

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do this...

```
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
    NSLog();
    break;

case 3:
   NSLog()
   break;

default:
   NSLog();
   break;
```

Comment: there is a way to combined 0 and 1 or 1 and 3?

Comment: If you don't 'break' inside a case then the instructions fall through the following (next) case(s) until it finds 'break'. So, you can have your generic logic together first and then have specific logic at the later case... E.g. case 0: case 2: NSLog(@"0, 1 and 2 cases"); case 1: NSLog(@"specific to case 1"); break; case 3: NSLog(@"case 3"); break;

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use ranges (a little bit less code). The following example illustrates it:

```
switch (value)
   {
      case 0 ... 2:
         NSLog (@"0,1,2 cases");
         break
      case 3:
         NSLog (@"3 cases");
         break;
      default:
         NSLog (@"anything else");
         break;
   }
```